# Organizing code files/XML files for Android SDK 

Tags: android, android-layout, organization, code-cleanup

Can someone provide some strategies as to organizing my project so that it is clean? Say I have a bunch of activities; is it good to place them all into a separate package, while putting other classes (such as custom Adapters) in another package to separate "logic" better?

Also, when creating XML files for layouts, how would I separate the layout XML files logically if I have some layouts that are for certain activities and other XML layout files for custom "rows" (to use with an Adapter) I don't want to just throw them all into res/layout -- it would become such a huge hassle when the project gets really big.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Say I have a bunch of activities; is it good to place them all into a
>   separate package, while putting other classes (such as custom
>   Adapters) in another package to separate "logic" better?

I'm not sure what best practices are, but here's how I organize my applications:  I tend to put my activities in `com.foo.appname.activity`, content providers in `com.foo.appname.content`, services in `com.foo.appname.service`, and generic utilities in `com.foo.appname.utils`.

For helper classes like `Adapters` that are only used by one activity, I typically make them static inner classes.  If they're used in multiple activities, I'd give them package level visibility in the activity package.

> I don't want to just throw them all into res/layout

I don't think that the `res` directories are allowed to have subdirectories, so the best you can do is to come up with a good naming scheme.  I typically prefix the layout file with the type: `activity_foo.xml`, `fragment_foo.xml`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

All these suggestions, of course are your choice. But when I develop something, I use to separate logical layer from "visible" layers and classes. I mean that I use different packages for

```
a) Activites
b) Classes or Objects
c) Interface classes
d) Database classes
e) Interaction with Database
```

I also create different packages for all of them, so you can organize them better. But this is always your choice.

And with your layout... I don't know if you can organize better the layout. When you generate your project, if you see, in your gen folder there's the R.java class. That class auto-detects folders such as layout, drawable, raw... But I'm not sure if you can make subfolders inside it.