# How to oraganise Android XML Layout files into folders

Tags: android, xml, layout, styles, directory

Is it posible to put these files into folders so they are in res/layout/1 and res/layout/2.

Comment: dude, accept the answer if you don't, nobody will answer you in the future.

Comment: @WinMyoHtet maybe he doesn't care about the future? :p

Comment: It only mentions xml organisation. For larger project is't not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible to create folders inside the standard folders in res.

Actually there is a question similar to yours on StackOverflow : [Organizing code files/XML files for Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653164/organizing-code-files-xml-files-for-android-sdk)  .

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the link ive been putting in bad names. This should help my 185 and counting layout count.